# Replacement for deprecated dijit/_Widget.getDescendants function?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using Dojo 1.9.1 and lodash.compat 1.3.1.

I am attempting to replace the deprecated [`dijit/_Widget.getDescendants()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dijit/_Widget#getDescendants) function. The deprecation warning says to use `getChildren()` instead, but that does not recurse.

This is what I have so far. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but results in an unhelpful `[object Error]` in IE7.

```
function get_widget_descendants(parent_widget) {
    return _(query("[widgetid]", parent_widget.domNode))
    .map(registry.byNode)
    .value();
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blah238/3eAxX/2/) demonstrating how it's supposed to work (<strike>I don't think JSFiddle itself works in IE7 though</strike>, actually it kind of does, see [this](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/311#issuecomment-13829654)).

**Update:** <strike>Actually, lodash itself doesn't pass [tests](http://lodash.com/tests) under IE7.</strike> Never mind that, the lodash.compat build does. However the compat build still has the same problem.

Does anyone have any ideas how to get this working under IE7? Has someone already solved this problem already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your fiddle, it looks like you are looking for the form widgets that are children of a widget.

`dojox/form/Manager` has a method called `inspectFormWidgets` that will do what you are lookiing for.

`dijit/form/FormMixin` has a method that you can reuse:

```
_getDescendantFormWidgets: function(/*dijit/_WidgetBase[]?*/ children){
    var res = [];
    array.forEach(children || this.getChildren(), function(child){
        if("value" in child){
            res.push(child);
        }else{
            res = res.concat(this._getDescendantFormWidgets(child.getChildren()));
        }
    }, this);
    return res;
},
```

You can call it using the following

```
require(['dijit/form/_FormMixin'], function(DijitFormMixin) {

    var widget = ...

    var descendants = DijitFormMixin.prototype._getDescendantFormWidgets.call(
        widget, widget.getChildren());
});
```

If you need to get more than just form widgets you can create a function that is similar to the `_getDescendantFormWidgets`.